# Zip file not seekable

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm trying to do some file manipulation on a zipped file. I'm a little confused on why the file like object that .open is returning a file like that's not seekable. Can any one shed some light on this?

This is the code I'm using. How can I make file_like's seekable?

```
zipped_archive = ZipFile(filepath, mode='r')
file_like = zipped_archive.open(file_name, mode='r')
file_like.seekable() # returns False
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ZipFile.open` method [returns](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/zipfile.py#L1318) a `ZipExtFile` object which [does not](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/zipfile.py#L694) implement seeking. The [default value](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/_pyio.py#L390) for seekable in `io.IOBase` is `False`.

I'm not sure why seeking was never implemented but I'd guess seeking by byte in a compressed file might be difficult for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in Python version 3.7 ([issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue22908))

Answer (score 0):

A very helpful and simple work around that helped me is to add seekable to the file I used:

```
def add_seekable_to_file(f):
    """
    If file f does not has seekable function -
    add seekable function that will always return true
    Args:
        f: the file
    Returns: the file f with seekable function

    """
    if not hasattr(f, "seekable"):
        # AFAICT all the filetypes that STF wraps can seek
        f.seekable = lambda: True
```

add_seekable_to_file(datazip.fp)